# UICollectionView with 2 sets of section headerViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

Is it possible to create a `UICollectionView` with 2 different sets of headers? For example, I want there to be one header that scrolls with the table and then stops at the top of the table, that floats normally like a `tableView`'s section header. But then I also want "sub" headers, that scroll with the table and then stop at the bottom of the outer header, and switch to the next one and so forth. There will be many "sub" headers, but only one header. I tried to do this with a `tableView`, but it got very messy and was wondering if there was a cleaner way to create this using a `UICollectionView`. Any tips?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. I'd recommend starting [with this](https://gist.github.com/toblerpwn/5393460).

You'll want to modify `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` to check the section number and return different behavior depending on whether or not section == 0.

Comment: Sure thing. That should get you going in the right direction. If you need more specifics, let me know.